# How to change screen resolution for Nvidia card

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-geforce

I have this hardware:

- cardA: Asus Geforce 210 Nvidia
- cardR: ATI Radeon HD4670
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

"Short" Story:

1. I wanted to test which of my graphical cards is the best.
2. I used Ubuntu 14.04 with cardA and the closed Nvidia driver recommended.
   If I changed to cardR I could not get any "graphical login".
3. With cardA installed and after a lot of struggle I succeeded with help of "Synaptic-Repositories-Alternative Drivers" to change from closed drivers to X.Org..Xserver..noveau...-driver.
   It worked excellent with that driver and I tested to watch a YT-streaming video that was a bit out of synch (sound/picture) before.  It looked OK.
4. I replaced to cardR that now works. I tested the same video.
   Both my CPU kernels was overloaded (100%) and video out of synch about 5-10s between sound and picture.
5. So I wanted to change back to cardA again as I now know it is better.
   But when I log in the resolution has changed so I can't do anything in the graphical window as I only can see a small part of it.
6. If changed back to cardR => it works with the right resolution.
   Before I could only use the cardA, now I can only use the cardR.
   This is a bit ironical as I wanted to know which of the two cards that was the best and now when I know

I am stuck with the bad one.

*Question: How can I get/set the right resolution for cardA?*

If I log in to an not updated or manipulated Ubuntu 14.04 with  "X.Org..Xserver..noveau.."-driver
both cards works fine with the right resolution (1920x1080).

---

How the problem was solved:

Thank you for the answers.

I hoped for a simple solution.
I realized the best solution was to install a new OS.
I bought a new grafic card (Nvidia Geforce GT720) so the CPU is probably the weakest link.

My conclusions are:
0.  Take backup.
1.  Install the new card.
2.  Install a new OS in a free partition.  (Test with a live-OS for ex on an USB-stick first).
It's always an advantage to change to a new clean OS now and then.
Every time I change to a new OS I document everything (checklist)  so it will go faster and safer for every time.

Tip:  To create a bootable USB-stick  ( in this example /dev/sdc is the USB-stick).
Linux>    cp   ubuntu-gnome-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso       /dev/sdc
    (sometimes I needed to create a new partition table (msdos) and format it (FAT32)).

Tip to save everything from Firefox and Thunderbird in the old OS to the new OS:
      (In this case from Ubuntu 14.04 to a new Ubuntu 14.04)
       Open and close Firefox or Thunderbird in the new OS so a new profile is created.
       Remove everything in the new profile folder.
       Copy the contents from the old Firefox or Thunderbird profile and paste it in the new profile.
      (Note!  Do not change the profile name).
       All addons/Extensions, mail, bookmarks, adresslists and so on will be exactely as before.

Comment: You should post above as an "answer" instead of editing the answer into your question! **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to "short" question:

- Remove the ATI card physically from the computer and reinstall.

There is also a "Long" answer that involves:

- Completely removing both drivers from the system
- reboot into `nosetmode`
- install the nVidia drivers
- reboot into normal mode

Comment: If you need more info on the long answe,r leave a comment here below, otherwise, if this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**